# How to open a url in a text box in a separate frame?

Tags: javascript, html, url, frames, frameset

I'm working on a webpage that will consist of a large main frame, with a small frame across the bottom with a text box and submit button. I need the submit button to change the main frame to the url in the text box. My code is below, but it only works if the url ends in a file name (e.g., index.htm). It won't work if the url ends in .com or /folder/ where index.htm is assumed. How can I fix it?

Here is my html/javascript. In my index.htm I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Menu Bar</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="*,30">
<frame src="main.html" name="main" id="main">
<frame src="menu.html" name="menu" id="menu">
</frameset>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The main.html is basically a blank html document (it has basic html, head, and body formatting only).

Here is menu.html:

```
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function go(){
URL = document.myForm.theURL.value;
parent.main.location=URL;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm">
<input type="text" name="theURL" size="50">
<input type="button" value="Go" onClick="go()">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try `parent.main.location.href` instead of bare `location`. Actually `location` is an _object_, which has properties, like `href` and methods like `reload()`. `frameset`s and `frame`s are not supported by HTML5, so there might be a confusion in "natural" behaviour of `location` object in modern browsers, when they need to implement `frameset`s.

Comment: @Teemu Still not working. Just loads a blank white page. Thanks though. Any other ideas? Also I'm writing this webpage for the nintendo 3ds so it only needs to work on netfront nx 1.0 if that makes a difference

Comment: Have you checked the content of the `URL` before using it as an url? Though I've to admit, I'm not familiar with Nintendo 3ds. Does a regular link work without a filename?

Comment: How do I make it use the id of the frame? I changed href to src but that didn't seemt o help any.

Comment: `parent.document.getElementById('main'). ...`. When you refer to `parent.main`, you'll get the `window` object in `main`. When using `id`, you can refer to the actual `frame` element in `frameset`.

Comment: I changed    parent.main.location=URL to    parent.document.getElementById('main').location.src=URL is that correct? It's still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this happens, but you can use this workaround:

```
function go(){
    var URL = document.getElementById('myForm').theURL.value;
    if (URL) {
        url = URL.split('/');
        if (url[url.length - 1].indexOf('index.htm') < 0) {
            url[url.length] = 'index.htm';
            URL = url.join('/');
        }
    } else {return;}
    parent.main.location.href = URL;
    // or: parent.main.contentWindow.location.href = URL;
}
```

To use this, you need to set `id="myForm"` to `form` element.

Comment: Will that work on all websites? I'm trying to make 'menu' a menubar that stays up and provides functions while you browse in 'main'

Comment: Still not working. Main has the background color set to silver so if the page changes I can tell, before it just changed to white. Now it doesn't change at all.

Comment: ok its almost working. if i type in http://www.google.com it loads a white page. but if i type in http://www.google.com/ it loads a google 404 error page saying /index.htm is not found on server

Comment: in my last comment the difference between the googles was they both start with http and the second has / at the end

Comment: ok its loading the same google 404 error page either way now, since google doesnt have a index.htm. the problem is not all pages use index.htm some use .php or .aspx or other file types

Comment: All this stuff for nothing... You can't load Google pages into a `frame`, they simply don't want their page to be loaded into a `frame` nor `iframe`. They do all they can to prevent it...

Comment: I tried loading stackoverflow in it and it just loads a white page. Does stackoverflow treat frames the same way?

Comment: it doesnt want to load any pages that dont end in index.htm. so it still isnt working

Comment: i removed the parts of the code that add index.htm and it works, except with googls, So, and probably any other sites that dont want to be loaded in frames. is there any way around that?

Comment: If there is, it's beyond my knowledge ; ) (4). If they want to prevent showing their pages out of the main window, why to hack the behaviour?

Comment: darn. my menubar should still work though. just not for certain sites i guess. i'll research around, maybe i can make a javascript menubar that loads in front of the page, but doesnt require the page to be in a frame. we'll see. thanks for all your help! i really appreciate it!